# reshape pandas wide column to long

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df like below

```
tno,tdate,buyprice,sellprice,qty,t1,t2
1,2017,10,20,5,teamA,teamB
2,2017,5,10,5,teamB,teamA
```

Expected op:

```
tno,tdate,buyprice,sellprice,qty,t1,t2
1,2017,10,20,5,teamA,NaN
1,2017,10,20,5,NaN,teamB
2,2017,5,10,5,teamB,NaN
2,2017,5,10,5,NaN,TeamA
```

What is happening is I am separating an internal transaction between 2 different team into in 2 different transaction.

I tried using `df.unstack()` and also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537945/reshape-wide-to-long-in-pandas) I am missing the way to tell pandas the way I want to unstack it.

Update1:

The larger context of the problem is:

```
tno,tdate,buyprice,sellprice,qty,Buyerteam,Sellerteam
1,2017,10,20,5,teamA,teamB
2,2017,5,10,5,teamB,teamA
```

There are 2 types of trades

1. Type1. where Buyerteam=NaN or Sellerteam=NaN (never both)
   and I calculate `qty*(buyprice or sell price)` to calculate expenditure of team. if buyTeam is NaN, I do `qty*sellprice`, `if sellTeam=NaN I do qty*buyprice`.
2. Type2. where both t1 and t2 are not NaN (the case in this question)
   I amtrying to convert type2 data into type1 data. But if I dont introduce NaN, my condition of `qty*(buyprice or sellprice)` cannot be applied

I hope my intent of introducing NaN is clear.

Comment: Is possible one output column for all teams?

Comment: Added some details to the problem

Comment: Sorry, I was offline. But I would like help you although better is create new question in this way. Can you change data sample with desired output for better explanation and better verifying my or another solutions?

Comment: sure @jazrael thanks for the kind help

Comment: The question was updated by me. Just that NaN is important for me. So expected o/p needs to be just as I have shown in the question

Comment: Maybe we dont understand well. I think if is possible create sample data by 2 types of trades with desired output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148997/discussion-between-pythonrcpp-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible one output column for teams use [`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857):

```
df = pd.lreshape(df, {'t':['t1','t2']})
print (df)
   buyprice  sellprice  tdate  tno      t
0        10         20   2017    1  teamA
1         5         10   2017    2  teamB
2        10         20   2017    1  teamB
3         5         10   2017    2  teamA
```

EDIT: If only 2 teams is possible use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), last for same order of columns use [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) and last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop('t2', axis=1), df.drop('t1', axis=1)], ignore_index=True)
       .reindex_axis(df.columns, 1)
       .sort_values(['tno','tdate'])
print (df)
   tno  tdate  buyprice  sellprice     t1     t2
0    1   2017        10         20  teamA    NaN
2    1   2017        10         20    NaN  teamB
1    2   2017         5         10  teamB    NaN
3    2   2017         5         10    NaN  teamA
```