# How do we do what R's spread function does in python?

Tags: python, r, pivot, pivot-table, spread

[1]: https://eksiup.com/p/og291345b64f #data.df

With R:

```
spread(weather3,measure,value)
```

How do we do the same operation in python? I've tried. but I get an error.

```
weather3.pivot(index=["year","month","day"], columns="measure", values="value")
```

gives

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-95fb6f73325f> in <module>
----> 1 df1.pivot(index=["year","month","day"], columns="measure", values="value")
D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   5917         from pandas.core.reshape.pivot import pivot
   5918 
-> 5919         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   5920 
   5921     _shared_docs[
D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot(data, index, columns, values)
    427             )
    428         else:
--> 429             indexed = data._constructor_sliced(data[values].values, index=index)
    430     return indexed.unstack(columns)
    431 
D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    297                         raise ValueError(
    298                             "Length of passed values is {val}, "
--> 299                             "index implies {ind}".format(val=len(data), ind=len(index))
    300                         )
    301                 except TypeError:

ValueError: Length of passed values is 8866, index implies 3
```

Comment: Please don't link images of code. Paste the code in the question instead. See [why you sholdn't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/389289) (same goes for image of short textual data)

Comment: Try not using a list input for parameters columns and values `weather3.pivot(index=["year","month","day"], columns="measure", values="value")`

Comment: I've tried. Now I get this error.  (Length of passed values is 8866, index implies 3)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537945/reshape-wide-to-long-in-pandas

Comment: This function("melt") corresponds to the 'gather' function.I want the corresponds of spread.

Comment: Then this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape-by-two-variables

Answer (score 2):

problem solved.

```
weather.pivot_table(weather, values='value', index=['year',"month","day"],
              columns='measure', aggfunc=sum)
weather2=weather.reset_index()
```