# Pandas DataFrame Wide to Long based on first column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I would like to transform a Pandas DataFrame of the following wide format

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', '1', '2', '3'], ['B', '4', '5', '6'], ['C', '7', '8', '9']], columns=['ABC', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'])

df =
   ABC  def  ghi  jkl
0    A    1    2    3
1    B    4    5    6
2    C    7    8    9
```

into a long format, where the values from the first column still correspond to the values in the lower-case columns. The column names cannot be used as stub names. The names of the new columns are irrelevant and could be renamed later.

The output should look something like this:

```
df =
   0  1
0  A  1
1  A  2
2  A  3
3  B  4
4  B  5
5  B  6
6  C  7
7  C  8
8  C  9
```

I am not sure how to best and efficiently do this. Can this be done with wide_to_long()? Then I would not know how to deal with stub names. The best would be an efficient one-liner that can be used on a large table.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.stack`:

```
>>> df.set_index('ABC') \
      .stack() \
      .reset_index(level='ABC') \
      .reset_index(drop=True)

  ABC  0
0   A  1
1   A  2
2   A  3
3   B  4
4   B  5
5   B  6
6   C  7
7   C  8
8   C  9
```

or use `df.melt` as suggested by @MustafaAydın:

```
>>> df.melt('ABC') \
      .sort_values('ABC') \
      .drop(columns='variable') \
      .reset_index(drop=True)

  ABC value
0   A     1
1   A     2
2   A     3
3   B     4
4   B     5
5   B     6
6   C     7
7   C     8
8   C     9
```

Comment: Many thanks! df.stack worked great (keeping the order of the columns). df.melt does not necessarily preserve the order if you have duplicate values in the ABC column I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and remove `variable` column:

```
df1 = (df.melt("ABC", value_name='new', ignore_index=False)
          .sort_index(ignore_index=True)
          .drop('variable', axis=1)
         )
print (df1)
  ABC new
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   A   3
3   B   4
4   B   5
5   B   6
6   C   7
7   C   8
8   C   9
```

If need more dynamic solution with generate first value of columns names:

```
first = df.columns[0]
df1 = (df.melt(first, value_name='new', ignore_index=False)
         .sort_index(ignore_index=True)
         .drop('variable', axis=1))
```

Comment: do you think this is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537945/reshape-wide-to-long-in-pandas) ?

Comment: @Umar.H - Almost, there is not removed column `variable`

Comment: Many thanks! However, df.melt does not necessarily preserve the order if you have duplicate values in the ABC column I believe.

Comment: @Fhtsm - Answer was edited by `sort_index` instead `sort_values`

Comment: @Fhtsm - and also `ignore_index=False` added to `melt`