# Convert Pandas DataFrame from Wide to Long Format

Tags: python, pandas

Given this DataFrame:

```
data = [['Tom', 'run', '2022-01-26', 'run', '2027-01-26'], ['Max', 'stop', '2020-11-16', 'run', '2022-04-26'], ['Bob', 'run', '2021-10-03', 'stop', '2022-01-26'], ['Ben', 'run', '2020-03-11', 'stop', '2013-01-26'], ['Eva', 'stop', '2017-11-16', 'run', '2015-01-26']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['person', 'action_1', 'time_1', 'action_2', 'time_2'])
```

```
  person action_1      time_1 action_2      time_2
0    Tom      run  2022-01-26      run  2027-01-26
1    Max     stop  2020-11-16      run  2022-04-26
2    Bob      run  2021-10-03     stop  2022-01-26
3    Ben      run  2020-03-11     stop  2013-01-26
4    Eva     stop  2017-11-16      run  2015-01-26
```

I want it to look like:

```
  person action        time
0    Tom    run  2022-01-26
1    Max   stop  2020-11-16
2    Bob    run  2021-10-03
3    Ben    run  2020-03-11
4    Eva   stop  2017-11-16
5    Tom    run  2027-01-26
6    Max    run  2022-04-26
7    Bob   stop  2022-01-26
8    Ben   stop  2013-01-26
9    Eva    run  2015-01-26
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas

Comment: you're saying "reorder" but it looks like you're actually reshaping - check out [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), e.g. [Reshape wide to long in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537945/reshape-wide-to-long-in-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(
    df,
    stubnames=['action', 'time'],
    i='person',
    j='num',
    sep='_'
).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  person  num action        time
0    Tom    1    run  2022-01-26
1    Max    1   stop  2020-11-16
2    Bob    1    run  2021-10-03
3    Ben    1    run  2020-03-11
4    Eva    1   stop  2017-11-16
5    Tom    2    run  2027-01-26
6    Max    2    run  2022-04-26
7    Bob    2   stop  2022-01-26
8    Ben    2   stop  2013-01-26
9    Eva    2    run  2015-01-26
```

Comment: @MichaelDelgado It appears that what many people call "wide to long" is actually just looking for "melt", but when you *actually* want "wide to long", this function is quite useful.

Comment: It is giving me an value Error: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row. Any tips? The exact error traces here: if df[i].duplicated().any():
raise ValueError("the id variables need to uniquely identify each row")

Comment: And another value error: ValueError: stubname can't be identical to a column name

Comment: Sounds like your actual data looks significantly different than the example data you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

One option with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) - it can handle non-unique indices:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(
    index='person',
    names_to=['action', 'time'],
    names_pattern=['action', 'time'])
```

```
  person action        time
0    Tom    run  2022-01-26
1    Max   stop  2020-11-16
2    Bob    run  2021-10-03
3    Ben    run  2020-03-11
4    Eva   stop  2017-11-16
5    Tom    run  2027-01-26
6    Max    run  2022-04-26
7    Bob   stop  2022-01-26
8    Ben   stop  2013-01-26
9    Eva    run  2015-01-26
```

Another option, using `.value`:

```py
df.pivot_longer(
    index='person',
    names_to='.value',
    names_pattern=r"(.+)_.+")
```

```
  person action        time
0    Tom    run  2022-01-26
1    Max   stop  2020-11-16
2    Bob    run  2021-10-03
3    Ben    run  2020-03-11
4    Eva   stop  2017-11-16
5    Tom    run  2027-01-26
6    Max    run  2022-04-26
7    Bob   stop  2022-01-26
8    Ben   stop  2013-01-26
9    Eva    run  2015-01-26
```