# how to convert a wide data frame to long dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Let's assume that I have the following data frame in pandas (assume all values and indices are string):

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'pair': ['(x,y)', '(x,z)', '(u,v)', '(u,w)'], 
         'A_1': [1, 4, 7, 5], 
         'A_2': [2, 5, 8, 7], 
         'A_3': [3, 6, 9, 1], 
         'B_1': [7, 0, 1, 0], 
         'B_2': [2, 1, 4, 4], 
         'B_3': [5, 3, 6, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

df

```
    pair    A_1 A_2 A_3 B_1 B_2 B_3
0   (x,y)   1   2   3   7   2   5
1   (x,z)   4   5   6   0   1   3
2   (u,v)   7   8   9   1   4   6
3   (u,w)   5   7   1   0   4   3
```

and I want to transform it to the following:

```
pair     A    B
(x,y)   A_1   B_1
(x,y)   A_2   B_2
(x,y)   A_3   B_3
(x,z)   A_1   B_1
(x,z)   A_2   B_2
(x,z)   A_3   B_3
(u,v)    ...
(u,v)     
(u,v)     
(u,w)     
(u,w)        
(u,w)
```

Where in the resulting table, A_i and B_i  mean the corresponding values in the first dataframe

value

```
    pair    A   B
0   (x,y)   1   7
1   (x,y)   2   2
2   (x,y)   3   5
3   (x,z)   4   0
4   (x,z)   5   1
5   (x,z)   6   3
6   (u,v)   7   1
7   (u,v)   8   4
8   (u,v)   9   6
9   (u,w)   5   0
10  (u,w)   7   4
11  (u,w)   1   3
```

How can I do it?

I know my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36537945/12850614), however, I couldn't properly map my dataframe to the OP's dataframe.  I am confused between using pivot_table and melt methods.

Comment: Do not omit the sample, as it is necessary for reproducibility.

Comment: @PandaKim  Ok. I can complete the first table. I leave the second table as it is because putting all the numbers there makes it hard to follow the pattern.

Comment: Are the pair columns indices? Are (x, y) tuples? If the data contains tuples, please do not create a table. Instead, provide code that can reproduce the sample DataFrame. Reproducibility is required to receive an answer.

Comment: being tuple or not does not play any role here. They can be any object. One can assume all of the string.

Comment: Although I have answered your question this time, it seems that your question is very time-consuming and annoying. The answerer also has limited time, so if you give them that impression, you may not get an answer. In general, if you do not receive an answer to your question within 30 minutes, there is a problem in your question.

Comment: @PandaKim Thank you for your answer. I wrote my question exactly same as the question in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df, i='pair', stubnames=['A', 'B'], j='j', sep='_')
         .sort_index(level=0, 
                     key=lambda x: x.map(pd.Series(range(len(df)), df['pair'])))
         .droplevel(1).reset_index()
)
```

out

```
    pair    A   B
0   (x,y)   1   7
1   (x,y)   2   2
2   (x,y)   3   5
3   (x,z)   4   0
4   (x,z)   5   1
5   (x,z)   6   3
6   (u,v)   7   1
7   (u,v)   8   4
8   (u,v)   9   6
9   (u,w)   5   0
10  (u,w)   7   4
11  (u,w)   1   3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to extend it to arbitrary numbers of columns; say A,B,C,D... do I just need to modify the argument stubnames?

Comment: In my actual dataframe  the column names A_i and B_i contain several under score. i.e., A and B themselves contain underscores! That makes your code does not work properly in my settings.  how can I modify your code to get the proper output.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot_longer) from pyjanitor

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
df.pivot_longer('pair', names_to = '.value', names_pattern = '(.*)_')

     pair  A  B
0   (x,y)  1  7
1   (x,z)  4  0
2   (u,v)  7  1
3   (u,w)  5  0
4   (x,y)  2  2
5   (x,z)  5  1
6   (u,v)  8  4
7   (u,w)  7  4
8   (x,y)  3  5
9   (x,z)  6  3
10  (u,v)  9  6
11  (u,w)  1  3
```

---

You can use [`pivot_longer`](https://siuba.org/api/experimental.pivot.pivot_longer) from siuba

```
# pip install siuba
from siuba import _
from siuba.experimental.pivot import pivot_longer

(pivot_longer(df, -_.pair, names_to = ['.value', None], names_sep = '_')
    .reset_index(drop = True))

     pair  A  B
0   (x,y)  1  7
1   (x,y)  2  2
2   (x,y)  3  5
3   (x,z)  4  0
4   (x,z)  5  1
5   (x,z)  6  3
6   (u,v)  7  1
7   (u,v)  8  4
8   (u,v)  9  6
9   (u,w)  5  0
10  (u,w)  7  4
11  (u,w)  1  3
```

Both of the functions can use `names_sep` or `names_pattern`

Comment: Thank you! where did you pass the names of new columns, A and B?

Comment: @Redshoes the special function `.values`